# How to change the aspect ratio of a figure in SymPy

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, aspect-ratio

I was trying to plot a simple torus with sympy. I would like to use the figure as an image.
Unfortunately the aspect ratio of the axes makes the image look elongated.

In the code I tried to change the `aspect_ratio` to `equal` like so:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
u,v = symbols("u, v")

r = 1
R = 2
p = plot3d_parametric_surface(cos(u)*(r*cos(v)+R), sin(u)*(r*cos(v)+R), r*sin(v), (u, 0, 2*pi), (v, 0, 2*pi), show = False)
p.aspect_ratio = "equal"
p.show()
```

but then this error occurred:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'q'
```

The error leads to `plot.py` on line 1296, where there is this if statement:

```py
if aspect != 'auto':
   aspect = float(aspect[1]) / aspect[0]
```

So I tried comment it out and then the code runs and the result changes slightly.

Also, according to this error (after setting the value to "aa") these options should work by default:

```
ValueError: 'aa' is not a valid value for aspect; supported values are 'auto', 'equal', 'equalxy', 'equalyz', 'equalxz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve the result you are looking for is by using [Sympy Plotting Backends Module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), where that bug has been fixed:

```py
from spb import *
plot3d_parametric_surface(cos(u)*(r*cos(v)+R), sin(u)*(r*cos(v)+R), r*sin(v), (u, 0, 2*pi), (v, 0, 2*pi), aspect="equal")
```

[image]

If you install the complete package you can easily create more fancy plots. For example, using Plotly:

```py
plot3d_parametric_surface(
    cos(u)*(r*cos(v)+R), sin(u)*(r*cos(v)+R), r*sin(v), (u, 0, 2*pi), (v, 0, 2*pi), "u",
    aspect="equal", backend=PB,
    wireframe=True, wf_n1=30, wf_n2=20,
    use_cm=True, color_func=lambda uu, vv: uu
)
```

[image]